# Bose-Einstein condensation as a phase transition

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate

1.How does a non-interacting system exhibit phase transition?

2.Is partition function of BEC is non-analytic (just like in the ordinary phase transitions)?

3.What is the order of BEC phase transition?

Comment: Non-interacting BEC seems to be a bit problematic. However, if you turn on the interaction, however small it is, the other questions can be answered clearly: it is continuous phase transition and a bunch of thermodynamics quantities diverge. I will review to give a full answer, when I have time ;-)